# Generating realistic Internet traffic in NS-3

Tags: network, traffic

I want to simulate a network in NS-3 and i want the traffic on this network be the real traffic. I found [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Isabelle_Lassous/publication/262314002_A_new_tool_for_generating_realistic_Internet_traffic_in_NS-3/links/00b7d53c8ebe8e70c7000000.pdf). This tool is based on PPBP (PPBP models on internet traffic) but i am really confused. This model only discuss about bit rate, but doesn't discuss about normal traffic such as http, ftp, smtp , etc. Real network traffic is combinations of http, ICMP, ftp traffic, etc. But this model doesn't discuss this.

So how can we say that this model emulates real network traffic?

I think if i use this article and model i don't emulate real network traffic.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The referenced paper is modelling the rate of traffic, trying to get it to behave like real traffic.  As they say the "model provides a simple and accurate network traffic generator that matches statistical properties of real-life IP networks."  They're not trying to model the mix of different kinds of packets.